# What does apostrophe mean for a register description in a datasheet e.g. 4'd5?

Tags: documentation

The datasheet lists something like this:

```
[0x01f] EPRXREG

    EPRXLock[3:0] = 4'd5;
    EPRXReLock[3:0] = 4'd5
```

I understand that it is an 8-bit register at address `0x01f`, it contains 2 fields and each of them is 4 bits wide (`[3:0]` and the `4` in `4'd5`). But what is `'d5`?

Other registers have

```
4'd12  1'b0  4'h4  4'hF  7'd32
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`4'd5` indicates a **four**-bit value, expressed in **decimal** as **5**. It's the same as `4'b101` (101<sub>2</sub> = 5<sub>10</sub>).

Likewise, `4'hF` is a four-bit value indicating `0xF` in hex; octal may also be seen (e.g. `4'hF` can also be denoted as `4'o17`)

Comment: Same syntax as used in Verilog. Probably some vague connection.

Comment: @TomCarpenter yep! They do say "standard Verilog convention". I did not get that's what it refers to.

Answer (score 3):

This is the notation used for values in Verilog.

The part before the `'` indicates the number of bits in the value - so `4'` means it is a 4-bit value.

The part after the `'` indicates the actual value.  There is a prefix indicating the number base, which will be `b` for binary, `o` for octal (rarely used), `d` for decimal, or `h` for hexadecimal.  (Exactly how to read values in binary, octal, decimal or hex is a separate question, which can easily be found online in any beginner's programming tutorial.)

Note that good style is usually that bitfields/flags are specified as `b`, so that the status of each flag can easily be seen.  Other values can be set in whatever number base makes sense for the value.

The number base can also be preceded by `s` to say that it is signed (typically `sd` for signed decimal) where required, where values can be positive or negative.  By default the number is unsigned (positive or zero only).  This gets a little more confusing for negative values because the `-` sign precedes the entire value, so an 8-bit signed value set to -23 would be `-8'sd23` and not `8'sd-23` as you might expect.